# Partial text search with Indexes in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, mongoose, partial

I have a Contacts collection with fields, name, email and mobile numbers with around 2 million records (This can go up-to 10 millions in some time). I want to run a case insensitive search on the name and email fields with `$regex` while using indexes.

I created text indexes on both name and email fields but the partial search is not working in this case. Further I also tried  index on name and email fields and used operator `$regex` with case insensitive option but in that case indexes are not being applied on on both these fields.

Here is what I have already tried:

**Tried:** `{'$text': { $search: searchstring }}` 
**Result :** Not able to search partial text

**Tried:** `{'name': { $regex: 'searchstring', $options: 'i' }}` 
**Tried:** `{'email': { $regex: 'searchstring', $options: 'i' }}` 
**Result:** Able to search partial text but not using index thus the search is very slow which beats the purpose

So basically what I need to achieve in MongoDB is similar to wild card function (%) in SQL Server with 1. Very fast search speeds (Split seconds) 2. Ability to do partial search.

An Example on SQL Server should look as follows

```
select * from tblUsers where username like '%amit%'
```

We are using NodeJS for backend and React for frontend.

Here are the indexes:
[
   {
       "v" : 2,
       "key" : {
           "_id" : 1
       },
       "name" : "*id*",
       "ns" : "contacts"
   },
   {
       "v" : 2,
       "key" : {
           "companyId" : 1.0,
           "isDeleted" : 1.0,
           "_id" : 1.0,
           "lists" : 1.0
       },
       "name" : "contacts_cmpId_isdel_id_lists",
       "ns" : "contacts",
       "background" : true
   },
   {
       "v" : 2,
       "key" : {
           "companyId" : 1.0,
           "isDeleted" : 1.0,
           "_fts" : "text",
           "_ftsx" : 1
       },
       "name" : "contacts_cmpId_nm_em_mb_unq",
       "ns" : "contacts",
       "background" : true,
       "weights" : {
           "emailAddress" : 1,
           "mobile" : 1,
           "name" : 1,
           "uniqueId" : 1
       },
       "default_language" : "english",
       "language_override" : "language",
       "textIndexVersion" : 3
   },
   {
       "v" : 2,
       "key" : {
           "companyId" : 1.0,
           "isDeleted" : 1.0,
           "emailAddress" : 1.0
       },
       "name" : "companyId_1_isDeleted_1_emailAddress_1",
       "ns" : "contacts",
       "collation" : {
           "locale" : "en",
           "caseLevel" : false,
           "caseFirst" : "off",
           "strength" : 2,
           "numericOrdering" : false,
           "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
           "maxVariable" : "punct",
           "normalization" : false,
           "backwards" : false,
           "version" : "57.1"
       }
   },
   {
       "v" : 2,
       "key" : {
           "companyId" : 1,
           "isDeleted" : 1,
           "name" : 1,
           "lists" : 1,
           "createdDate" : 1
       },
       "name" : "contacts_cmpId_isdel_name_lists_crdt",
       "ns" : "contacts",
       "background" : true
   }
]

Here is the explain query

`db.getCollection('contacts').find({companyId: ObjectId('5bfcd53c19ebe6727a000d90'), isDeleted: false, 'name': { $regex: 'test1User', $options: 'i' }}).skip(0).limit(100).explain('executionStats')`

and its output:

"executionStats" : {
       "executionSuccess" : true,
       "nReturned" : 1,
       "executionTimeMillis" : 3634,
       "totalKeysExamined" : 613865,
       "totalDocsExamined" : 613840,}

Comment: Please add the output of `db.yourCollection.getIndices()` to your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54103900/edit)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Here is the output

Comment: There is no text index, as far as I can see...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Yes, as Partial Search does not require text indexes I believe as they are useful for full text search. Let me know if you have any other suggestions to address this problem.

Comment: For a text search like `{'$text': { $search: searchstring }}` to work, there has to be a text index. Period. Create a text index, run the query. Problem solved ;)

Comment: There is already text index with `name - contacts_cmpId_nm_em_mb_unq` and we tried `{'$text': { $search: searchstring }}` but text search does not support partial text in this case. For example, if there are 3 email address: "rohitsharma@email.com", "rohit@email.com" and "rohits@email.com" and we search by "rohit" it will only return "rohit@email.com" and not all three of them. What we need to do is to return all the three matching results.

Comment: Ok, add an example doc and the expected results. And for gods sake, format your code 

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Here is the link of the [doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xZznvcsa7LZSC_o5eoAbjsJnqRPQc5FoZGlB_0Q6pxk/edit?usp=sharing) explaining the requirement in detail.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Let me know if you have an update to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using mongoose since its mentioned in the tags. 
If so you can use regex like this

```
UserModel.find({name:new RegExp(nameVariable,"i")}); //"i" makes it case sensitive
```

try this it should solve the problem

Comment: This did not work either as this is same as operator `$regex`. This does not use indexes.

Comment: This did not work, any other approach you can share?